# Github emptied my folder containing React app

Tags: git, github

I am currently trying to make a website that has ExpressJS for server-side and React for the front-end. After successfully integrating React into my Express app I decided to push my directory into GitHub. My react app is placed in a directory called `front`. After the push, I realized that I cannot open the `front` folder. It also has a different logo. Other folders have a logo of a single folder yet this one has one big and one small folder as it's logo. I have tried deleting the `.gitignore` file from the React app and push again, but nothing changed. And when I pulled the project, the folder is empty.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I assume you can still see your files in local. Can you do  `git status` and share it with us. also can you do a `git log` and confirm that it match with the list of commits in github?

Comment: And If you don't have your files in local but you are sure you commit your changes before. Check `git reflog`

Comment: This is what I got when I did `git status`:
`On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)

        modified:   front (modified content, untracked content)

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")`

Answer (score 0):

You have created a repository in a repository. A so called submodule.

You have two choices:
You can delete the .git folder in the front folder and you will have just one repository.

Or you handle two repositories and do a push in the front folder.

Comment: I deleted the .git folder and now when I try to push it says everything is up to date.

Comment: Did you do: `git add .` and `git commit -m "commit message"`

Comment: Yes I did those

Comment: If you havent made any commits so far, try deleting the .git folder in your project and start a clean repo with `git init`